# SoapUI : ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER"

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, database-connection, soapui

I'm using JDBC in soapUi to get some data from the database but I'm encountering this error. Does anyone know how or where will I put the User Type specific in the connection string or JDBC configuration? [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqa4H.png)

Comment: What query are you running? or db connection configuration in jdbc step?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#05_11

Comment: SYS and SYSTEM should *never* be used for data retrieval. These are administrative accounts for the database. For reporting purposes, create a user with read only access.

Comment: @Rao The query is not the problem. It's the db connection configuration in jdbc step, it was asking to connect as SYSDBA.

Comment: That is what i was asking for.  Assuming that you identified the issue. So resolved?